# Gerrit: All activity for a user in a given time period

Tags: gerrit

I would like to get ALL activity for a given user in a time period. That is, all revisions they have done on patches they own or on patches others own, all comments and all reviews. 1) Are there other activities in Gerrit that I am missing? 2) Will the following query do what I want?

```
(owner:'USER' OR commentby:'USER' OR reviewedby:'USER' OR author:'AUTHOR' OR committer:'COMMITTER') and (before:end-date after:begin-date)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search is ok and I think there aren't any search clauses to be added.

Just some comments below:

1) You can replace "owner:USER OR commentby:USER" to just "from:USER"

2) You can replace "USER" to "me" to get info from your own user

See more info at Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html)